# Tint 2 UIButton on single Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, tint

I have two button say button1 and button2 declared as

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
```

What I want to do is, when button1 is click button 2's tint color should be changed, so its like both button1 and 2 are same, when I click on button1 the tint should also effect in button2 as if button2 is also clicked, so its appearance should be like clicking two buttons at once when I click on button1. Is this possible?

My UserInteraction for button2 is disabled as I dont need its click event. On my button1 click I need button2 to also tint giving it an appearance like button 1 and 2 are simultaneously clicked.

EDIT:
 Some of you guys are still not getting my point. Imagine that on the run time screen there are two buttons, Button1 and Button2, imagine Button1 is invisible. Now if I click on Button1 it should look on the screen that I just clicked Button2. Setting tint color will only set the button2 tintcolor but it will not give the button clicked effect.

Comment: Those are not button declarations, those are button actions which you have named `button1:` and `button2:`.

Comment: I've updated it, I only need action for button1

Comment: @Gamerlegend Please see my answer and only add the code it to you first action...

Answer (score 0):

Yes all you have to do is connect to outlets to the buttons...Call them whatever you want. Pu this code in **BOTH** your IBActions.

```
   your1stButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
   your2ndButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In the different actions change the color and be sure to change `your1stButton` and `your2ndButton` to your outlets name.

Comment: jst a question, hw will the button2 tint, when I click on button1, for eg: if I set your2ndButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; on button1 action, now this will effect only if I click on button2.Right? How can I see the tint of button2 in button1.

Comment: @Gamerlegend If you add your2ndButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; to your button 1 action the it will get called when you press your button 1.

Comment: I agree, button its not tinting, ur code will set the tint color but it will not make button2 tint when i click on button1

Comment: @Gamerlegend Did you connect the outlet of button 2?

Comment: @Gamerlegend How are you making the button invisible?

Comment: yes i connected outlet of button2, to let you know my button 2's user interaction is disabled so when will i see the tint of button 2? And i am not making it invisible it was jst to give an idea of how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set button1 and button2 to as an `@property` (outlet) in your header, as well as declaring the methods. In the `- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;` method you can set the tint color like so: `self.button2.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];`

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
  self.button2.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender
{
  self.button1.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: button2 is not tinting, i created its outlet, but here u are setting the tintColor to red, u are not calling the button for tint

Comment: I had trouble getting the tint color for the button to change in projects targeted for iOS 7, idk if it is a bug. This code worked for me on ios 6+, but not 7

Comment: jst a question, hw will the button2 tint, when I click on button1, on button1 action u have set tint for button2, now this will effect only if I click on button2. Right?

Comment: Since button2 is set as a property and you only have the button1 touch method set up, it will change the `tintColor`, which is a property of button2. Basically what you did with the declaring the outlet is you declared the button2 as a variable

Comment: You dont need the `- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender` method anymore since the `userInteraction` is disabled anyway

Comment: still u r setting the tint color not calling it, when I click my button1 for 1st time I need to see the tint effect of button2 along with button1

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;
{
   btn1.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
   btn2.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];


}
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender;
{

btn1.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
   btn2.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];


}
```